# How do I fix my Javascript function that does not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am starting to learn Javascript and I do not understand the following:

I need to execute the method **"pay"** in order to pay all the different persons; so, I need to complete the function **"salary"**. The function receives an array object; all those objects "know" how to execute the method "pay". Also, I want to store the result in the array **"result"**.

I did this but it seems it's not working:

```
function salary($persons) {
  $results= [];

  $persons->pay();

  return $results;
}
```

What am I missing? What's wrong with my function?

Comment: Hey, So reading your question a few times I have the feeling you are trying to learn JavaScript by taking a rocket to the moon. Alright that's a little hyperbole but but it's important to remember to walk before running. Anyway perhaps taking a look at sites like w3schools.com/js and working through your questions one at a time until you have a solution be a good use of your time.

Comment: That looks like PHP rather than Javascript...

Comment: @RobinZigmond How would you do that in PHP only?

Comment: Main recommendation I would have generally, is to always look at the compilation error provided, and give it into your question. It should give you at least a partial hint on what the problem is and where it lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->` is not Javascript syntax.

To construct one array by performing an operation on each item of another array, use `.map`:

```
function salary(persons) {
  return persons.map(person => person.pay());
}
```

```js
function salary(persons) {
  return persons.map(person => person.pay());
}

console.log(salary([
  { pay: () => 5 },
  { pay: () => 10 }
]));
```

Since this isn't PHP, there's no need to prefix variables with `$` either.

Comment: Because since `persons` is an array (right?), it makes sense to call each individual item of the array a `person` object (from which you can then access the `.pay` property of that object).

Comment: Thank you for replying.. i got this question in my mind: Is not possible to use php inside a javascript function?

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Dude, thank you very very much. Last question: how would you do to perform the same but using PHP?

Comment: I pretty much never use PHP, but maybe something like `array_map(function($person) { return $person->pay() }, $persons)`, no idea if that syntax is right though

Comment: Yeah, i dont know how to do that in php only :/